# PDO constructor / php

Tags: php, pdo

Trouble is:

If I'm getting the constructor string (in string format) with all arguments from an `xml` file `PDO` fails with: `could not find driver`.
pseudo: `$pdo = new \PDO( registry::get('dsn') );`

If I assign it to a variable and use the variable in the constructor, it fails again.

```
$dsn = registry::get('dsn');
$pdo = new \PDO( $dsn );
```

If I echo the very same string to screen and copy and paste it to the constructor all works fine.

Anyone had the same issue or has an idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: Try `var_dump($dsn)`.

Comment: Perhaps `registry::get()` is returning an array? So you must do `new PDO($dsn[0]);` or similar.

Comment: What is the string exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Random guess: The string is still wrapped in XML tags, e.g.:

```
<dsn>mysql:...</dsn>
```

When printing it to *the browser*, the tags are interpreted by it and not shown.

Comment: It almost definitely has *something* to do with XML vs text.  Something tells me `registry` is using some "Simple *ML" API rather than DOMDocument.

Comment: You've got it @cHao, but whn i get the string enclosed within xml tags i use syntax (string)$enclosedpart.